# codeigniter, currently unable to handle this request

Tags: php, codeigniter, server

I am creating a CRM system in code igniter. There are several roles to perform a specific functionality. The two roles are Company Admin and Super Admin. Company Admin can create a user for only his company. while super admin can create user for any company by accessing the admin panel of that company's administrator. When I try to add the user as a company admin it works fine, but when i try to add the user from company admin, when i click on the add user button it give "currently unable to handle this request." error instead of loading the add user view

add user View:

```
<main style="height: 1492px;" id="main" data-match-height="window-height" class="add-user-page">
        <div class="quick-links-holder">
            <div class="inner">
                <ul class="quick-links clearfix">
                    <li>
                        <div style="height: 100px;" class="link" data-match-height="quick-link">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>add_user_files/icon-5.png" alt="icon">
                                <strong>VÆRDI KORT</strong>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div style="height: 100px;" class="link" data-match-height="quick-link">
                            <a href="#">
            <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>add_user_files/icon-5.png" alt="icon">
                                <strong>PLAN KORT</strong>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
            <div style="height: 100px;" class="link" data-match-height="quick-link">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>add_user_files/icon-5.png" alt="icon">
                                <strong>SWOT ANALYSE</strong>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div style="height: 100px;" class="link" data-match-height="quick-link">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>add_user_files/icon-5.png" alt="icon">
                                <strong>ACTION PROGRAM</strong>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="toggle-btn"><span>QUICK LINKS</span></a>
        </div>
<div class="main-holder">
            <div class="container">

                <header class="title-secondary">
                    <h1>Users</h1>
                </header>
                <?php if(isset($user_success)) { ?>
                    <div class="notices success">
                        <a href="#" class="close" title="close">×</a>
                        <strong>Success: </strong><?php echo $user_success; ?>
                    </div>
                <?php } ?>
                <?php if(validation_errors()) { ?>
                    <div class="notices error">
                        <a href="#" class="close" title="close">×</a>
                        <strong>Error: </strong><?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
                    </div>
                <?php } ?>
                <div class="panel">
                    <div class="panel-title arrow-none btn-none">
                        <h3>Add User</h3>

                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-content">
                        <div class="inline-form">
                             <?php echo form_open_multipart('admin/add_user'); ?>

                                <fieldset>
                                    <table>
                                        <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><label>Username</label></td>
                                            <td><input name="username" placeholder="Username" type="text" ></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><label>Password</label></td>
                                            <td><input name="password"  placeholder="Password" type="password" ></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><label>Email</label></td>
                                            <td><input name="email" value="abc@abc.com" placeholder="Email" type="email" ></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td width="120"><label>First Name</label></td>
                                            <td><input name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" type="text" ></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><label>Last Name</label></td>
                                            <td><input name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" type="text"></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><label>Profile Picture</label></td>
                                            <td>
                                                <div class="file-upload">
                                                    <input type="file" id="file" name="profile_pic"  />
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><label>User Role</label></td>
                                            <td>
                                                <label class="selectbox">
                                                    <select name="role">
                                                        <option value="administrator">Administrator</option>
                                                        <option value="employee" selected="selected">Employee</option>
                                                    </select>
                                                </label>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td colspan="2" class="text-right">
                                                <input name="submit" class="button" value="Submit" type="submit">
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody></table>
                                </fieldset>
                            </form>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Controller function that calls the add user page:

```
public function adduser ($data=FALSE){

    $data['logo']= $this->site_logo();
    $data['company_name']=$this->site_company_name();
    $data['fullname']=$this->site_user_full_name();
    $data['picture']=$this->user_picture();
    $data['logo']= $this->site_logo();
    $data['menu'] = header_menu(); 
    $data['dropdownItems'] = $this->TasksModel->get_dropdownItems();
    $data['employees']=$this->AdminModel->load_employees();
    $this->load->view('html/header',$data);
    $this->load->view('add_user', $data);
    $this->load->view('html/footer');
}
```

Button to load the add user view:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/adduser" class="button larg">Tilføj medarbejder</a>
```

Comment: how are you deciding it is company admin or super admin?

Comment: the roles are saved in the data base, when the user is logged in his role is saved in the session. for example , for super admin session veriable has super admin stored in it

Comment: can you copy and paste whole error? check error logs in cpanel if you can.